# Holomorphic function into a Stein domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I read in an article the following claim:

Consider the Stein Domain $D = \{z = (x,y) \in \mathbb C^2 : |x| < 1, |x y |<1\}$. Then, any entire non-constant holomorphic function $\mathbb C \to D$ is contained in the $y$-axis.

I don't even know where to start. How could one prove such a result?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this correctly? What about the constant map $z \mapsto (\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$? (If we exclude constant maps, I believe the result follows by considering the maps $z \mapsto x(z)$ and $z \mapsto y(z)$ as single-variable holomorphic functions, then applying Liouville's theorem twice.)

Comment: Oh yes, every non-constant holomorphic function. I will modify the question. Could you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a function $z \in \mathbb C \mapsto (x(z), y(z)) \in D$ is holomorphic iff the component functions $z \mapsto x(z)$ and $z \mapsto y(z)$ are individually holomorphic.

So let's look at the first component function, $z \mapsto x(z)$. We know that $|x(z)| < 1$, which is to say that this first component function is a bounded entire function. By Liouville's theorem, we have $x(z) = c$, for some constant $c \in \mathbb C$ with $|c| < 1$.

Suppose that $c \neq 0$. Then the inequality $|x(z)y(z) | < 1$ reduces to $|y(z)| < |c|^{-1}$. So the second component function $z \mapsto y(z)$ is bounded. Applying Liouville's theorem once more, we learn that $y(z) = k$, for some constant $k \in \mathbb C$ with $|k|<|c|^{-1}$. But then both component functions are constant, contrary to assumption.

The only alternative is that $c = 0$. But then $x(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$, so the image of the function is contained in the $y$-axis.

Comment: Merci, that's perfect.